# C function to execute arbitrary Linux syscall forwarding

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I need to write a C function that takes in input a Linux syscall number and all the registers execute the syscall and returns the result of the syscall. How can I do this in in C? Is there any existing function that act in this way?

(Edit) I cannot just call the [syscall](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) method because I want to execute the syscall remotely in another computer and I need a way to set the state of registers as if they were in the calling environment and to set everything else needed for a correct execution.

What I want to do is some sort of a syscall forwarding. One pc wants to execute a syscall and forwards its execution to a second pc getting back the results.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html

Comment: Thank you Barmar, your answer was perfect for my previous question. I missed an important point, I edited the question.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using an RPC library.

Comment: I think it's more complicated than your description suggests. You can't just set registers, system calls are dependent on the entire state of the process and operating system. Like if you call `read()`, your file descriptors are not necessarily the same as the ones on the remote system.

Comment: `syscall` *does* set the register expected by the syscall.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, I edited again the question. RPC library sounds good, is there something existing that do what I need?

Comment: @immibis yes but the execution of the syscall is done in another pc. How can you transfer all the information that you need? Does syscall takes as a parameter this information?

Comment: @AntonioRomeo Oh, you didn't say "all the information", you said "all the registers". Registers are where the parameters to the syscall go. And of course, `syscall` takes a bunch of parameters, makes sure they're stored in the right registers, then does the syscall.

Comment: @AntonioRomeo I don't know if the thing you think you need is what you actually need.